# Div positioning

Tags: css

I have a div tag which has table header on it and the rest of the table content is in another div. I need to make the position fixed when vertical scrollbar is scrolled so that the table header will be seen on vertical scrolling.Upto this point its not a problem because using div position:fixed,it will work. But the problem is during horizontal scroll the header should not be fixed. is there any horizontal and vertical scroll event to make the position fixed and absolute?Please help

Comment: To be assist us, can you post your HTML?

Comment: Why are you using another div instead of tbody?

Answer (score 0):

Getting elements to respond differently for horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling sounds like it would be handled best with Javascript. CSS can give you a fixed element, but it will be fixed for both x and y scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you. pure ccs: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html